# How to recalls each observer streams with CombineLatest in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables, angular14, angular15

How can I update/refetch `accountModel$` latest values each time the component gets loaded?

**CLIENT_LIST**

```
import { InjectionToken, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '@app/core';

export const CLIENT_LIST = new InjectionToken('clients', {
    providedIn: 'root',
    factory: () => {
        const userService = inject(UserService);
        return userService.getActiveClientsForUser());
    }
});
```

**GROUP_LIST**

```
import { InjectionToken, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '@app/core';

export const GROUP_LIST = new InjectionToken('groups', {
    providedIn: 'root',
    factory: () => {
        const userService = inject(UserService);
        return userService.getActiveGroupsForUser());
    }
});
```

**my-component.ts**

```
export class MyComponent {
   readonly accountModel$ = combineLatest({
        clients: inject(CLIENT_LIST),
        groups: inject(GROUP_LIST)
    });
}
```

**my-component.html**

```
<app-my-account
        *rxLet="accountModel$; let accountModel;"
        [activeClients]="accountModel.clients"
        [activeGroups]="accountModel.groups"></app-my-account>
```

I tried to initialize `accountModel$` from constructor, but the constructor does not call `InjectionToken` factory 2nd time.

Comment: If you provide them in the providers array of your component, they'll get re-created every time the component is created.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I tried providers: [{ provide: GROUP_LIST

, useValue: GROUP_LIST

 }] @maxime1992

Comment: My bad, you won't be able to achieve what I said with InjectionToken. I think if you want to keep your current strategy, the next best thing to do is to provide a 3rd one that'd be a subject, and whenever you create a component in the constructor you next to that subject. Then in GROUP_LIST, return `yourSubject$.pipe(switchMap(() => userService.getActiveGroupsForUser())`. This way, all your components get the same observable for group list, and you're just able to emit in it whenever you want to update all the subscribers